# How a novice user better understand the Q/A

Tags: syntax

A novice user reading Q/A here:
I sometime need to just understand the syntax and meaning of commands exampled here. where is the best place to find it?

Comment: Please google Wolfram Mathematica Documentation Center.

Comment: You might find [this wiki question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/142) useful, especially [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18606/142) and [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/142).

Comment: `Help` > `Wolfram Documentation` is the documentation. It is literally the best documentation I have ever seen in my life.

Answer (score 4):

Built-in Mathematica symbols can be looked up directly in a Mathematica session by selecting the symbol/command text and hitting F1. This is also available in the menu: Help --> Find Selected Function.

The online Wolfram language reference includes categories for digging through the documentation, but it also includes a search box which can be used to quickly lookup symbols, built-in functions, packages, and related topics:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/